# Is it possible to edit the CSS of an existing webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, cross-domain

Specifically, what I'm trying to do is create a mobile version of a site I don't have access to. The best approach I can think of is this:
My site executes their php search file and then displays the results page, but first modifies its DOM to use my CSS. Is it technically possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site can definitely access web content from another site, filter/transform it however it wants, and then forward the result wherever it wants. It is not a simple problem, potentially, as so much web content is dynamic.  For example, if the source site has content that's formatted with CSS that's dynamically built by JavaScript, it'd be fairly difficult to come up with an automated transformation.

Whether the original site's owners will be *happy* about your site doing that is a separate issue.

Comment: Also worth noting is the tendency for pages to change, breaking the implementation.

Comment: Indeed.  Overall this falls into my personal "don't ever bother to do it" category :-)